# Simple question about htaccess rewrite

Tags: html, url, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I don't know much about rewrite, I would like to do the following thing...

I have http://www.website.com/web.php?id=3

But I would like http://www.website.com/web/title/3

is this possible? (title is the url web title tag)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes it is possible. you can add following in `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^web/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\$ web.php?id=$2
```

more tips: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Comment: Thanks Zain but it's not working for me :S nothing I get exactly the same with or without this on the .htaccess :S any Idea?

Comment: make sure your `.htaccess` file is located in the root directory.

Comment: it's located on the root directory :S

Comment: Did you change all your URLs to fit the new pattern http://www.website.com/web/title/3? You have to do this on your own, mod_rewrite just translates your new URLs to their original equivalent.

Comment: I just added this:RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^categoria/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([0-9]+)\$ categoria.php?id=$2